# What is MySQL wait state 'wait/synch/mutex/innodb/lock_mutex'

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, amazon-rds

We have an application (on Amazon RDS MySQL 5.7; `db.m5.24xlarge`; 96 cores) that takes in a lot of data, in parallel processors+queues. It mostly goes to one table, with primary keys not spreading over multiple queues. Entries are batched in transactions.

When we increase the amount of processors+queues, there's a tipping point where all wait time is spent on `wait/synch/mutex/innodb/lock_mutex`, but I can't really find what that means. It even takes CPU cycles, so these are spinlock mutexes?

Performance insights:

[image]

I already disabled the deprecated query cache and [adaptive hash index](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/04/12/is-adaptive-hash-index-in-innodb-right-for-my-workload/), because they are all mutex-governed and don't help our `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` heavy workload.

So, what is the resource governed by `wait/synch/mutex/innodb/lock_mutex`, and do I have control over it, either with settings or perhaps using a lower transaction isolation level?

Edit:

`show engine innodb status` shows:

```
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 10591578
--Thread 47139002062592 has waited at lock0lock.cc line 6415 for 0  seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x2b2be1000058, Mutex LOCK_SYS created lock0lock.cc:454, lock var 1

wait has ended
--Thread 47138574509824 has waited at lock0lock.cc line 6415 for 0  seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x2b2be1000058, Mutex LOCK_SYS created lock0lock.cc:454, lock var 1

wait has ended
--Thread 47136822810368 has waited at lock0lock.cc line 6342 for 0  seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x2b2be1000058, Mutex LOCK_SYS created lock0lock.cc:454, lock var 1

wait has ended
--Thread 47137720436480 has waited at lock0lock.cc line 6342 for 0  seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x2b2be1000058, Mutex LOCK_SYS created lock0lock.cc:454, lock var 1

and many more
```

Edit: also interesting in the [MySQL 8 changelog](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-relnotes-en/news-8-0-21.html), it says:

> InnoDB: To improve concurrency for operations that require access to
> lock queues for table and row resources, the lock system mutex
> (lock_sys->mutex) was replaced by sharded latches, and lock queues
> were grouped into table and page lock queue shards, with each shard
> protected by a dedicated mutex. **Previously, the single lock system
> mutex protected all lock queues, which was a point of contention on
> high-concurrency systems**. The new sharded implementation permits more
> granular access to lock queues.

So am I affected by that? I'll just have to perform a 'quick' upgrade...

Comment: Please show us the table(s) and queries.

Comment: It's a good idea to upgrade anyway, because 5.7 is approaching its end of life. I can't say what the cause of the mutex blockage was. In my experience, it's sometimes caused by degraded server hardware. So it might be solved simply by doing a failover of your RDS instance to the standby (assuming you use multi-AZ), or else just recreate it.

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
AWS RDS instance type? Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: The question pertains the what resources are governed by `wait/synch/mutex/innodb/lock_mutex` and the LOCK_SYS system, how and when this mutex is used (db space or system internals), what is its behavior as spinlock vs 'lock wait', etc. This information is really hard to find. But, my last edit is probably the answer. The MySQL upgrade will happen anyway, so I will probably answer the question with the results.

Comment: lock wait information will be available for analysis if you could post the information requested 2022-0806 at 23:21.  Thank you

Comment: I already am well on my way to confirming that MySQL 8.0.21+ doesn't have this problem. The load with 64 concurrent processes doing exactly the same only costs 'CPU' and 'SQL handler'. I was not ready to post an answer, but I will soon, after some more tests.

Comment: @Halfgaar  Thanks for your pursuit of resolving this with your moving to 8.0.21.  We appreciate your posting of your observations.  In about a week, please consider posting the data requested 2022-0806 at 23:21 for current workload analysis to provide suggestions for improving performance even more.  View profile for contact info and free Utility Scripts to assist with performance improvements.

Comment: @WilsonHauck the actual live upgrade is planned for somewhere next week, I hope, so it'll have to wait a bit more. Also, while I appreciate the offer, I'm unsure how much actual queries I can post (it's not open source), but I can also say I'm no beginner at writing multi-threaded/concurrent applications, be it SQL or not. Currently, when not in mutex wait, the server does about 100k queries/s at 10% CPU load (of 96 cores) and 3000 IO/s. But of course, perhaps you see it as a challenge :)

Comment: More speed is always a plus.  What I thrive on.

Comment: You may wish to provide data requested from your development system to get a 'pre-live' workload analysis.  There are likely things to be adjusted before going live.  UPTIME should be at least 24 hours before gathering your data, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sharded lock-sys was introduced in [this commit](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/commit/1d259b87a63defa814e19a7534380cb43ee23c48).

They have good commit messages, which explains what lock-sys is (which is the original question I had):

> WL#10314 - InnoDB: Lock-sys optimization: sharded lock_sys mutex
>
> The Lock-sys orchestrates access to tables and rows. Each table, and
> each row, can be thought of as a resource, and a transaction may
> request access right for a resource. As two transactions operating on
> a single resource can lead to problems if the two operations conflict
> with each other, Lock-sys remembers lists of already GRANTED lock
> requests and checks new requests for conflicts in which case they have
> to start WAITING for their turn.
>
> Lock-sys stores both GRANTED and WAITING lock requests in lists known
> as queues. To allow concurrent operations on these queues, we need a
> mechanism to latch these queues in safe and quick fashion.
>
> In the past a single latch protected access to all of these queues.
> This scaled poorly, and the managment of queues become a bottleneck.
> In this WL, we introduce a more granular approach to latching.

So, this wasn't anything you have control over as a user, aside from reducing concurrency.

Test running the system on MySQL 8 shows a marked improvement:

[image: Amazon performance insight showing no wait states]

On a 96 core MySQL server, these are 64 queue processors (=64 processes) operating on the same table, but all on different rows (mostly updating). You can see that there is no mutex wait state anymore, aside from CPU and SQL handling, which is good.